# Monotouch: UIDocumentInteractionController preview right bar button not working in iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I am working within an Universal app supporting both iPhone and iPad. I currently have the use for a UIDocumentInteractionController to present a PDF and offer some options on that PDF (most importantly Print functionality). Everything appears to work on the iPad flawlessly with the overview coming up and the RightBarButtonItem in the Preview properly allowing my to print. However, working with the iPhone, when I click the RightBarButtonItem I receive the error:

```
Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].
```

Resolving this with typical action sheets is relatively simple:

```
ActionSheet.ShowFromTabBar(this.TabBarController.TabBar);
ActionSheet.ShowFromToolbar(this.NavigationController.ToolBar);
```

However with the cooked in document controller, I'm finding it hard to grasp how to do it. The code for the interaction controller is very standard compared to other implementations I've found on here so I'm sure there is something small I am missing. Here is the implmentation:

```
invoiceInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(url);
invoiceInteractionController.Delegate = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass(this);

InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
    if (!DeviceHelper.IsIPhone())
        invoiceInteractionController.PresentOptionsMenu(NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem, true);
    else {
        invoiceInteractionController.PresentPreview(true);
}
});
```

For now if the device is iPhone I am just skipping right to the preview as you can see in this code. The problem is within the preview controller when the upper right bar button item is pressed which throws the aforementioned issue. However, as an aside, replacing PresentPreview() with:

```
invoiceInteractionController.PresentOptionsMenu(new RectangleF(320,320,0,500), this.NavigationController.Toolbar, true);
```

This also evokes the same error.

I'm almost wondering if it has something to do with my delegate class which is as follows:

```
public class UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    UIViewController viewC;

    public UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass (UIViewController controller)
    {
        viewC = controller;
    }

    public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview (UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return viewC;
    }

    public override UIView ViewForPreview (UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return viewC.View;
    }

    public override RectangleF RectangleForPreview (UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return viewC.View.Frame;
    }
}
```

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to essentially mark this as resolved as it doesn't cause the app or controller not to work. Eventually I believe I will have to just replace the whole thing with my own roll of the controller as it isn't really friendly to branding / skinning. It would be really nice if it offered the ability to present from the tab bar.

One thing I did notice is when presenting it within navigation controllers within a tabbar that is defined in Interface Builder, the doc controller will throw the same warning but just never appear. Creating the tabbar programmatically and explicitly defining the the RectangleF will allow the controller to show up but still throws the warning.

My best guess is PresentPreview(true) assumes it should present from the control that called the event which unfortunately is a button in an action sheet presented from the right bar button. I am open to any more suggestions to get the warning to dissapear.